# What is the logic behind the output of my python code?

Tags: python

I got a reference for the below snippet of program from a website, but going through it I am not able to understand the output:

```
data = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
def fun(m):
    v = m[0][0]

    for row in m:
        for element in row:
            if v < element: v = element

    return v
print(fun(data[0]))
```

I can figure couple of output through the print statement, e.g.

```
v = m[0][0]  --> output 1

1st iteration
for element in row: --> output 1, 2
if v > element: v = element  --> output 2.
```

But the 1st for loop is confusing for me as well the print statement outside the function.

Sorry for dumb question, but I need to clear my logic.

Thank you in advance

Comment: what the number of bracket in front of data, 3? so m[0][0] return the last bracket, and it's is [1, 2] not 1.

Comment: The current code should return the max value within `data[0]`.  You seem to have the right idea in the question, just keep moving to the next `row` in `m`

Comment: In a nutshell: it iterates through all the numbers individually, and whenever it finds a smaller number, it assigns it to `v` (with `v` starting out as the first number). Since `v` starts out as `1`, no other number is smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your input, the function will return the maximum value in the list of list, but it makes some assumptions on the format of your input.

This is that your `m` is a `list` of `lists` with the internal lists having numerical values in them. As the other answers say, the output for your case is 4 and the value of v will increase by one on each loop.

However, to give an example where `v < element` doesn't give `True` everytime if your input was `[[1,4],[2,1]]` the value of `v` will be as follows (the comments will give the values in order of the loop) :

```
# your input : m = [[1,4],[2,1]]

def fun(m):
    v = m[0][0] # v = 1

    for row in m: # v = 1, v = 4, v = 4, v = 4
        for element in row:
            if v < element: # False, True, False False 
                v = element

    return v # v = 4
```

Comment: I guess, I have my answers, Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
data = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
```

subsequently `data[0]`, that is passed to the function as **m**, is

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

then

```
v = m[0][0]
```

is

```
1
```

Then your loop

```
for row in m:
    for element in row:
        if v < element: v = element
```

Here you're iterating over `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` , and then over each element in nested list `[1, 2]` and then `[3, 4]`, and trying to compare each number in the list to 1, so v becomes 2, then 3 and then 4, so upon the code prints

```
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Just running the code print

> 4

Line by Line :

```
data = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
```

We have a list of list of list (depth 3)

so : `fum(data[0]) = fum([[1, 2], [3, 4]])`

```
v = data[0][0][0] = 1
```

`for row in data[0]` means we iterate in the elements of `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`, so first element is `[1,2]` second element is `[3,4]`

`for element in row` means we will iterate in the elements of row so : element = 1, then 2, 3, 4

```
if v < element: v = element
```

Just means v takes the value of the max value of (v, element)

So this functions takes the first element of the list data and returns the max value of the n lists of m elements contained by the first element of data.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's go over what's being passed to `fun()`:

```
print(data[0])  # This outputs the first item in 'data[]'
# Output: [[1,2], [3,4]]
```

Now let's break down the first line of the function. We have `v=m[0][0]`.

```
print(m)
# [[1,2], [3, 4]] (What we passed to the function)

print(m[0])
# [1,2] (The first item in the list)

print(m[0][0])
# 1 (The first item of the the first item in the original list)
```

So this line is just getting the very first number in the nested list.

Next, the for loops:

```
for row in m:
    print(row)

# [1,2] (iter 1)
# [3,4] (iter 2)
```

This is just cycling through all the list items in the list that was passed to the function.

Then, for each of those cases, we're iterating through each number:

```
for row in m:
   for element in row:
       print(element)
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
```

Lastly, the `if` statement is comparing the current element (1, 2, 3, and then 4) to the current value of `v` (which starts off as 1). If `v` is less than the current element, we replace `v` with the current element.

So, for example, in the first iteration of the loop, we compare:

`if v < element` (`if 1 < 1`)

Which is false, so we move on to the next loop, where we compare:

`if 1 < 2`

This is True, so we execute the next line which states `v = element` (or `v = 2`)

So on the next loop, we are now comparing:

`if 2 < 3`

Which is True, so `v` will again be assigned the value of element

At the end of both `for` loops, we end up returning the largest value of `m`, in this case: 4